# Could we put a disclaimer warning on asked CAD questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think SE user interface has a mechanism to display a disclaimer of warning when adding a tag thats highly abused.

If so then could we ask for a disclaimer for CAD tags saying something to the effect:

"CAD software questions are not generally ontopic, so make sure your post clarfies how the question is about **graphic design**!".

Do you think this would make sense? and if not why?

Comment: There are 0 questions tagged [CAD]. I don't see how this would help: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cad

Comment: @PieBie Well there is [autocad], [solidworks], [autodesk-fusion-360], [autodesk-inventor],[catia]... all of which are CAD applications. Just because they arent tagged CAd does not mean most of these questions arent CAD related

Comment: Need it for video as well...

Comment: @joojaa: Fair enough, shows how little I know about this software. Tbh, I have no idea whether this is possible on our site, and how to implement this. Will have to confer with other mods/staff on how to do this. IF there is consensus in the community that this is needed, and the regular help/explanation text of a tag is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think such a thing would be **very** helpful for both **CAD** questions and **Video** questions.

In most instances, comments merely tell the user where to go look for an answer. As opposed to the questions garnering direct answers here.

<kbd>solidworks</kbd><kbd>autodesk (all)</kbd><kbd>catia</kbd><kbd>autocad</kbd><kbd>adobe-after-effects</kbd><kbd>adobe-premiere</kbd><kbd>video</kbd>